# How to embed an element-ui component into a vuetify component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, element-ui

I am new on vuejs and I use in my project two libraries that are element-ui and vuetify. So I add a component la-table of element-UI in my template which is more composed of component vuetify and after its integration the page does not appear any more without any error which is displayed. I do not know why I have this result but I tried v-flex and template but the problem is not solved.

```
    <template>
     <div style="background-color:#E0E0E0">
      <router-view></router-view>
     <v-app-bar
      color="teal darken-3"
      dark
      class="navbar"
      style="position:fixed; top:0; z-index:10"
    >
    <v-layout row>
       <v-flex sm="6">
        <img  src="../assets/logoBni.jpg" style="width:50px; height:50px"/>
       </v-flex>
     </v-layout>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-flex xs="12"><p class="text-justify" style="margin-right:250px">UTILISATEUR</p></v-flex>
          <div class="my-2">
            <v-btn small v-on:click="allerLogin" width="150px">Se deconnecter</v-btn>
          </div>
     </v-app-bar>
      <v-row style="margin-right:1100px;margin-top:100px;position:fixed; top:0; z-index:10" class="navbar">
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" offset-sm="3">
          <v-card height="330px" width="350px">
            <v-card-title class="orange darken-3">
              <span class="headline">Menu</span>

              <v-spacer></v-spacer>

              <v-menu bottom left>

                <v-list>
                  <v-list-item
                    v-for="(item, i) in items"
                    :key="i"
                    @click=""
                  >
                    <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
              </v-menu>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text>
              <v-row>
                <div class="my-2">
                  <v-btn small v-on:click="allerAccueil" width="150px">Accueil</v-btn>
                </div>
              </v-row>
              <v-row>
                <div class="my-2">
                  <v-btn small v-on:click="allerClient" width="150px">Client</v-btn>
                </div>
              </v-row>
              <v-row>
                <div class="my-2">
                  <v-btn small v-on:click="allerOperation" width="150px">Operation</v-btn>
                </div>
              </v-row>
              <v-row>
                <div class="my-2">
                  <v-btn small v-on:click="allerBilletage" width="150px">Billetage</v-btn>
                </div>
              </v-row>
               <v-row>
                <div class="my-2">
                  <v-btn small v-on:click="allerCaisse" width="150px">Caisse</v-btn>
                </div>
              </v-row>
              <v-row>
                <div class="my-2">
                  <v-btn small v-on:click="allerDroits" width="150px">Gestion des droits</v-btn>
                </div>
              </v-row>

            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    <div>
       <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      height="1000"
      max-width="900"
      outlined
      color="orange lighten-5"
      style="border-style:solid"
    >
    <div style="margin-top:100px; margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px">

      <!--Modal Formulaire de creation d'utilisateur-->
        <v-row justify="center">
          <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on" style="margin-bottom:30px; margin-left:500px;">Ajouter un utilisateur
                <v-icon>account-add-outline</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">Création d'un utilisateur</span>
              </v-card-title>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-container>
                  <v-combobox
                    v-model="model"
                    :items="items"
                    :search-input.sync="searchCombo"
                    :hide-selected="hideSelected"
                    label="Choisir un utilisateur"
                    :multiple="multiple"
                    persistent-hint
                    :small-chips="chips"
                    :clearable="clearable"
                  >
                  </v-combobox>

                  <div style="border-style:solid">
                    <v-row style="margin-left:200px">
                        <v-col
                          cols="12"
                          md="8"
                        >
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="firstname"
                            :rules="nameRules"
                            label="Nom *"
                            required
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                    <v-row style="margin-left:200px">
                        <v-col
                          cols="12"
                          md="8"
                        >
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="firstname"
                            :rules="nameRules"
                            label="Prenoms *"
                            required
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                    <v-row style="margin-left:200px">
                        <v-col
                          cols="12"
                          md="8"
                        >
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="firstname"
                            :rules="nameRules"
                            label="Code exploitant *"
                            required
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                    <v-row style="margin-left:200px">
                        <v-col
                          cols="12"
                          md="8"
                        >
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="firstname"
                            :rules="nameRules"
                            label="Matricule *"
                            required
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                  </div>
                </v-container>
                <small>*indique les champs obligatoire</small>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Annuler</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Enregistrer</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </v-row>
        <!-- Formulaire de creation d'utilisateur-->

   <!-- add code that prevents the page from displaying -->
    <el-table
      :data="tableData.filter(data => !search || data.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))"
      style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column
        label="Date"
        prop="date">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        label="Name"
        prop="name">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        align="right">
        <template slot="header" slot-scope="scope">
          <el-input
            v-model="search"
            size="mini"
            placeholder="Type to search"/>
        </template>
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-button
            size="mini"
            @click="handleEdit(scope.$index, scope.row)">Editer</el-button>
          <el-button
            size="mini"
            type="danger"
            @click="handleDelete(scope.$index, scope.row)">Supprimer</el-button>
         </template>
       </el-table-column>
     </el-table>
     <!-- add code that prevents the page from displaying -->

     </div>


     </v-card>

   </div>

   </div>
   </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find, it's about fixing js errors in looking in console by inspecting the code.

But also verified although you have copy code level of code on vuetify or element-ui